# InvalidCastException unusual issue

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I don't know what happened with my project and my ideas end right now.
I am getting error "InvalidCastException - can not be cast namespace.secondwindow to namespace.MainWindow. 
[image: Here is screenshot.]
 Probably something goes wrong with project, this solution works before and I dont get any exceptions, build works pretty well. Next I add .ico to windows and I try some "new" keyboard shortcuts and right now, I didn't remember that I was testing aplication after that or not.

I check all files, I didn't found anything what can be wrong. I wonder why Intelisense tells well but during tests I get exceptions. If I comment this lines or write it other way I will get "the same" exception in other line.

If anybody had this issue or know what can be wrong, please answer :)

Comment: Your Application.Current.MainWindow is not of type MainWindow but of type Statistics.

Comment: The Exception pretty much tells you everything you need to know.